# Find if list values are true from the first items

Tags: python, boolean-operations

I have a JSON array, each item contain a boolean list of 10 values, I need to decide for each item if it's flagged as true or false by performing AND on the first three items in boolean list.

I am looking for some "elegant" non-looping way to implement this.

Example of the json:

```
[
  {
  "eFcw":{
    "available":true,
    "isFcwvCalculated":false,
    "clqId":-1,
    "clqId_ASIL":-1,
    "asilFailures":4098,
    "IPB_fcwResults":{
      "FCW_withA_status":[false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false]
      }
      }},
      {
  "eFcw":{
    "available":true,
    "isFcwvCalculated":false,
    "clqId":-1,
    "clqId_ASIL":-1,
    "asilFailures":4098,
    "IPB_fcwResults":{
      "FCW_withA_status":[false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false]
      }
      }}]
```

Comment: Do you have a sample input and expected output?

Comment: That looks like json - not python. `false` and `true` are not python.

Comment: I'm implementing in python

Answer (score 3):

You could try using [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) on a slice of your list of booleans:

```
all(list_of_bools[:3])
```